# Arranging Cascade the CDialogs in MFC with CascadeWindows function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, user-interface, mfc

How can I arrange dialogs programmatically in MFC in cascade format, other than simply using `SetWindowPos` based upon the position of the previously displayed window?

The Dialog position is to be loaded from the registry in my app, so we use:

```
SetWindowPos(NULL,x,y,cx,cy,SWP_NOZORDER);
```

...for the dialog.  After that if we use the CascadeWindows function it doesn't seem to work for this Dialog, though it works for other dialogs in the same parent window.  It seems the `CascadeWindows` function has no effect on windows that have called `SetWindowPos`; can anybody please confirm?

If so, do we have to use only SetWindowPos to arrange the dialog's cascade, or is there another way?

Comment: SetWindowPos doesn't change any attribute of the window other than its position and size, so there shouldn't be any way for it to affect CascadeWindows. Does the window cascade properly if you don't call SetWindowPos?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your dialog is having window style: `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` or `WS_EX_TOPMOST`. `CascadeWindows` will not arrange windows with that styles.

I tried an MFC sample dialog based application with the following code:

```
void CTestCascadeDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    this->SetWindowPos( NULL, 100,100,500,500, SWP_NOZORDER );
    CascadeWindows( NULL, MDITILE_ZORDER, NULL, NULL, NULL );
}
```

And I could observe that my dialog was cascaded successfully.